# jQuery click not working in Firefox only

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

It's been a while since I posted on here so I hope this isn't bad form. But I figured it's easier to look at the page for a live example: http://www.wrangelloutfitters.com

The drop down menu works in IE, chrome, and Safari, but not Firefox. Tested in Firefox 11.0, and Firefox 25.0.1. I recently converted it from a CSS hover to jQuery events for touch screens and it's working fine. Just not in Firefox which leaves me baffled.

For summary and posterity if someone else needs this after the site has been changed basic code is:

```
<script>
    function hideAllDrops (){
        document.getElementById('mainA-sub').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('mainB-sub').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('mainC-sub').style.display='none';
    };

$(function(){
    $( "html" ).click(function() {
        hideAllDrops ();
    });
        $( "#mainA" ).click(function(){
        hideAllDrops ();
        document.getElementById('mainA-sub').style.display='block';
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
```

---

```
<li><a class="menuOpt" id="mainA">Guided Hunts</a>
    <div class="nav_sub last" id="mainA-sub">
    <div class="nav_sub_wrapper">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="/subPage">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/subPage01">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/subPage03">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><div class="sub_nav_end"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: just give a try adding type="text/javascript" in the place where you have only tag as <script>. Its just a try.

Comment: Can you get a console output ?

Comment: nope. Thanks though. @ Saurabh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox Console : [00:40:05,423] ReferenceError: event is not defined @ http://www.wrangelloutfitters.com/:64

your dropdown link throws error. please refer your console in firebug.
you not passed event as a argument and still you are using event.stopPropagation();
instead you should use like below

```
$( "#about-wrangelloutfitters" ).click(function(event) {
hideAllDrops ();
document.getElementById('about-wrangelloutfitters-sub').style.display='block';
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Yep, and also, using the word 'event' might lead to errors and mislead in code reading. Also, it's an IE reserved word wich will trow some bug somehow.

Comment: Thanks so much. I guess I need to do some more reading. But that was the initial issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `'` in ,`getElementById('mainA-sub')`

```
    $( "html" ).click(function() {
        hideAllDrops ();
    });

  function hideAllDrops (){
    document.getElementById('mainA-sub').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('mainB-sub').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('mainC-sub').style.display='none';
 }
```

Comment: Sorry it's in real code, wasn't in posting. Good catch but not the problem.